# Data not sync in ColumnTemplate in ShieldUI Grid component

Tags: shieldui

I got two questions about ShieldUI grid component.
Q1. when editing is enabled, you need to click cell to toggle edit/display mode. Is it possible to make it always showing editor component?
Q2. When I attach ShieldUI components like numeric text box or date picker to ColumnTemplate, no matter how I change the value in custom UI component. It doesn't sync the value showing in the component back to data source in the Grid. Do you know the solution for my above issues?
Thanks.